# Why connection with sakis3g not detected by network manager

Tags: software-center, internet, usb-modem

I have a Photon 3g Modedm and I am using sakis3g to connect to internet.

After connecting to net I can browse internet in *firefox* and also I am able to install updates and softwares using *apt-get*.

But when I open **software center** *install* option is greyed out as in picture 
[image]

and I wont be able to install softwares till I disable network manger by running this code in terminal

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

I want to know how this work? Also If I want to run this script while I login instead of typing this in terminal every time, where I can put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the code in Launcher.. When you click connect launcher that will too execute and stop network manager.. Thats how i use..

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

In the software center, copy the name of the app you want to install without the version number - in this case `plotdrop`. See the screenshot below:

**Note:** My install button is disabled too.

[image]

Then open up your terminal and type `sudo apt-get install plotdrop` and it will install just fine. In your case you will type 'Y'. See screenshot below:

[image]